# Replace all 0's if all row is 0, NA and 1

Tags: text-processing

My question is like this:

I want to check all the rows from the 4th column till the end whether the field values are **only** 0 (formatted as `0.00`) , 1 (formatted as `1.00`) or `NA`, and if so replace the `0` values with `0.001`.

For example a row like this:

```
MA_10 49498 49499 NA NA NA NA 0.00 NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA
```

and here is the expected output:

```
MA_10 49498 49499 NA NA NA NA 0.001 NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA
```

but it should not touch a row like this:

```
MA_10 49499 49500 NA NA NA NA 0.00 NA 0.50 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1.00 NA NA NA NA
```

since it has a value different than NA, 0 and 1 which is 0.50.

I did smt like this but not gonna work since it will also replace 1's.

```
#!/bin/bash -ue
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }

NR != 1 {
    for (i = 4; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i = "0" || $i= "1") {
            $i = "0.01";
        }
    }
}

{ print $0 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`01.awk`**:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
skip=0
{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i !~ /NA/ && $i!=0 && $i!=1){
            skip=1
            break
        }
    }
}
!skip{gsub(/0\.0+/,"0.001")}
1
```

The for loop tries looks for a not-NA, not-zero and not-one field in a line from the fourth column on. If found, `skip` is set to 1, thus the line

```
!skip{gsub(/0\.0+/,"0.001")}
```

is not executed and the `0.00` does not become `0.001`.

Execute the script with

```
awk -f 01.awk inputfile
```

PS: `#!/bin/bash -ue` on the top of your attempt does not really make sense, since you wrote an awk script, not a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following (which I have splitted across several lines using the "line continuation" with backslashes at end-of-line for readability):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{delete a; nzero=0;\
      for (i=4;i<=NF;i++){\
        if ($i==0) a[++nzero]=i;\
        if ($i!=0 && $i!=1 && $i!="NA") {print; next;}\
      }\
      for (i=1;i<=nzero;i++) {$a[i]=0.001;}; print;}' input.txt
```

- This will parse all lines to see which of the fields (starting with the 4th field) have a value numerically equal to zero, and store the field numbers in an array `a` and the number of such fields in `nzero`.
- At the same time, it will check if any inspected field does *not* match 0, 1, or "NA". If so, the line is printed "as is" and execution skipped to the next line.
- If no "illegal" fields are found, the array `a` is parsed, and all field numbers stored there replaced by `0.001`.

Note that the syntax `delete a` to clear the array requires GNU Awk. For other implementations, use `split("",a)` instead.

The same as Awk script (let's call it `replace.awk`):

```c
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}

{
  delete a;
  nzero=0;

  for (i=4;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if ($i==0) a[++nzero]=i;
    if ($i!=0 && $i!=1 && $i!="NA")
    {
      print;
      next;
    }
  }
  for (i=1;i<=nzero;i++) $a[i]=0.001;
  print;
}
```

Use as

```
awk -f replace.awk input.txt
```

Comment: I tried and it worked well! Also, thanks for the explanation, I really like the logic :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `awk` way where we select the record to be modified by means of a regex.

```
$ awk '/^([\t]*[^\t]+){3}([\t]+([01][.]00|NA))+$/ && gsub(/0\.00/, "0.001") || 1' file
```

**Regex decoded:**

`^([\t]*[^\t]+){3}`  traverse the first three fields (fields are TAB separated) of the current record.

`([\t]+([01][.]00|NA))` is the form of the "good" field from the fourth onwards.

place a `+` after the good field and take till the end of record, meaning, all fields after the third are "good". And that means this is the line we want to modify.

The `gsub` will replace the "0.00" into "0.001"

===============================

Below is the awk code to generate the regex on the fly and do the changes.

```
$ gudFld="[01][.]00|NA" \
    awk '
       function enc(arg) {
         return "(" arg ")"
       }
       BEGIN {
         sp = "\t"
         s = "["  sp "]"
         S = "[^" sp "]"
         f_ = s"*" S"+"; f = enc(f_)
         f3 = f"{3}"
         e = enc( ENVIRON["gudFld"])
         g_ = s"+" e; g = enc(g_)
         pat = "^" f3 g"+" "$"
       }
       $0 ~ pat && gsub(/0.00/, "&1") || 1
' file
```

And in case we want to be paranoid and account for the possibility the pattern `0.00` might appear in the first three fields, then we can replace the last line with the following. Here we are running gsub only on field 4th onwards.

```
$0 ~ pat {
   match($0, f3)
   f123 = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
   f4_end = substr($0, RLENGTH+1)
   gsub(/0.00/, "&1", f4_end)
   $0 = f123 f4_end
}1
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! I tried yours too and it also looks cool and works well.

Comment: This looks nice, but I don't think you can start that line (in the first snippet) with `&&`. It raised a syntax error for me.

Comment: yeah, the first snippet also did not work for me so how to fix it? I am trying to keep the code in a single line but keeps giving a syntax error..

Comment: Changed it to  a one liner now.